# Where f(x) is increasing and where it is decreasing?

Tags: functions, derivatives

I have this function - $f(x)=(-1)^{3x}\cdot x + (-1)^{2x}\cdot x^{2}$

I have to find where its increasing and decreasing.
Actually i dont know how to start, i trid to derivate but without success.
Does anybody has an creative idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: This function takes complex values, so what does it mean for it to be increasing?

Comment: $x_2 \geq x_1 \rightarrow  f(x_2) \geq f(x_1)$

Comment: But the symbol $>$ doesn't make sense for complex numbers. For example, what is $f(1/2)$ and how does it compare to $f(0)$?

Comment: $f(x)$ is over the real numbers.
So $f(1/2)$ is not in the domain.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase. What is $f(1/2)$? What is $f(0)$? Is it true that $f(1/2) \ge f(0)$? Can you answer these three questions?

Comment: the idea of increasing is incoherent, because it occupies a complex value for all $x \neq c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: The answer for for $f(1/2)$ is the same answer for $g(-1) ;$ $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$ over the real numbers, its undefined, not in the domain.
$f(0) = 0$

Comment: So what is the domain of your function?

Comment: @user I dont know how to find that.

Comment: @AndresMejia What do you mean ?

Comment: Domain is the set of values that are allowed for $x$.

Comment: @GyroGearloose I know the definition of Domain.
But dont how to find that in this specific function.

Comment: @Noam you have to define what it means for $a<b$ in the complex plane to get a reasonable answer for this question. For example, compute: $f(\frac{1}{6})$ and $f(1)$.

Comment: $x =\frac{1}{6}$ is not in the domain because $ (-1)^{3\cdot \frac{1}{6}}$ is not in the real numbers, and the function is over the real numbers.

Comment: I think the domain is $x \leq 0$ or $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Where did you find this problem? Perhaps some context could give some hint. At a quick look, only integer numbers will give you real values for f.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Why ?
BTW, my answer for the domain is incorrect.

Comment: Your above statement that $f(\frac 1 2)$ is undefined contradicts that  $x\ge \frac 1 2$ should be part of the domain.

Comment: Why what? ?????

Comment: I propose that you make a copy of this question on your computer, delete the question here, take some time to clear your mind, rephrased it with more info and pose it again in an improved form.

Comment: @Noam so the domain is all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$? then $f$ should be defined along the lines of $f:\mathbb{Z} \cup\{\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}: 2,3|q\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?? I am very confused by how exactly this function is defined. As has been asked previously, can you define the domain? Or perhaps show where you found this question?

Comment: @GyroGearloose for what i think
I have 2 options - 
1. $x$ is integer.
2.$x$ is rational number $x = \frac{p}{q}$
and then $p$ must be even.

Comment: As you have seen by yourself, your $f$does not give real values for $\frac 1 2$. You can easily see that it doesn't for $\frac 1 2 +\frac 1 n$, too. At a quick look, it doesn't give real values for anything but x\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @AndresMejia
This is the  the question -
Let $f(x)=(-1)^{3x}\cdot x + (-1)^{2x}\cdot x^{2}$ .Find where $f(x)$ is increasing and find where it is decreasing.

Comment: @GyroGearloose $f(\frac{4}{3}) = \frac{28}{9}$
$x$ can be rational and not integer.

Comment: Ouch, I think I see your problem. You compute $(-1)^{2x}$, in this case $(-1)^\frac 8 3$ by taking $(-1)^8=+1$ and then $(+1)^\frac 1 3=+1$. You should see $-1$ as $e^{i\pi+2k\pi}$.

Comment: Take a look starting at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Computation_of_ab_where_both_a_and_b_are_complex , don't get fooled by the small size of the paragraph and don't expect a quick understanding, this thing is rather complicated.

Comment: Correction: $-1=e^{i\pi+2ki\pi}$, not $e^{i\pi+2k\pi}$.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Sorry for my misunderstanding (?), But If we talk about the real numbers ($\mathbb{R}$),
$ (-1)^{\frac{8}{3}} = \sqrt[3]{(-1)^{8}} = \sqrt[3]{1} = 1$

Comment: @GyroGearloose If we were talking about the complex field, you were right.

Comment: And why not $(-1)^{\frac{8}{3}} = (\sqrt[3]{(-1)})^{8} = \mbox{undefined}^8$? If the computation was so straigthforeward, then you could do $\color{red}{(-1)^3x=((-1)^2)^x\cdot(-1)^x=(+1)^x\cdot (-1)^x=(-1)^x}$. It is not so simple.

Comment: The intermediate results are complex, in a way of speaking, so we have to "think complex" here.